# Lua : how to get rows and column count in excel file with the help of lua script

Tags: lua

is there any inbuilt function or object in Lua script to  get rows and column count in excel file. suggest a way how to get length of rows and column by lua script

Answer (score 0):

```
local function get_rows_cols_in_excel_file(excel_file)
   -- returns two values: number of rows and number of columns
   -- returns nothing if file not found
   local vbscript_filename = os.getenv"TEMP".."\\getrowscols.vbs"
   local vbscript = [[
      On Error Resume Next
      Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
      objExcel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      Set objBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(Wscript.Arguments(0))
      If not objBook Is Nothing Then
         Set Rng = objBook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange
         Wscript.Echo Rng.Rows.Count & ";" & Rng.Columns.Count
         objBook.Close False
      End If
   ]]
   local vbs_file = assert(io.open(vbscript_filename, "w"))
   assert(vbs_file:write(vbscript))
   vbs_file:close()
   local command = '"cscript //nologo "'..vbscript_filename..'" "'..excel_file..'""'
   local pipe = io.popen(command)
   local rows, cols = pipe:read"*a":match"(%d+);(%d+)"
   pipe:close()
   if rows then
      return tonumber(rows), tonumber(cols)
   end
end

local your_excel_file = [[C:\Path\to\your\excelfile.xls]]
local rows, cols = get_rows_cols_in_excel_file(your_excel_file)
print(rows, cols)
```